# Different $this and &get_instance() after load library

Tags: php, codeigniter

in Windows (Apache2 + PHP 5.2.9-2 + Codeigniter 2.1.4)

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        echo $this === $CI; // echo 1
        exit;
    }
}
```

but,

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $CI =& get_instance();
        echo $this === $CI; // echo 0
        var_dump($this->pagination); // Undefined property: Welcome::$pagination
        exit;
    }
}
```

what happened ?

---------------- added --------------

codeigniter's controller code ...

```
class A {
    protected static $instance;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance = &$this;
    }

    public static function &get_instance()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

class B extends A {
}

$b = new B();
$refA =  &A::get_instance();
$refA->a = 'aaa';
echo $b === $refA; // echo 0 in windows(php 5.2.17), 1 in Linux (php 5.2.17)
```

is this bug ?

Comment: I get `1` in both situation.

Comment: I tested *the update* code in Windows 7 64bit using XAMPP v3.0.12 with PHP 5.4.4, still get `1`.

Comment: @HashemQolami Yes, i guess the problem occurs with php5.2.x and Windows